# Nodejs GPIO pin usage - gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership

Tags: node.js, gpio, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to use nodejs on my Raspberry PI to read a value from a light sensor which is attached. I can get the reading out of a python program and can confirm my setup is correct.

Below is the program

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");

gpio.open(12, "output", function(err) {     // Open pin 12 for output 
    gpio.read(12, function(err,value) {         // Set pin 16 high (1) 
        console.log(value);
        gpio.close(12);                     // Close pin 16 
    });
});
```

Below is the error message

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Samples $ node GPIO.js
Error when trying to open pin 12
gpio-admin: failed to change group ownership of /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio18/direction: No such file or directory
```

I had earlier installed pi-gpio module as shown below

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Samples $ npm install pi-gpio
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the newest version of pi-gpio and gpio-admin.

The path for gpio in kernel since 3.18.x has been changed to `/sys/class/gpio/`. The old version of pi-gpio and gpio-admin only supported `/sys/classes/virtual/gpio/`. The newer version also supports `/sys/class/gpio/`.

**Edit:**

Run

```
npm update pi-gpio
```

If the problem still exists, build the newest version of gpio-admin yourself.

Choose a directory you want to put gpio-admin in, and run

```
git clone https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin.git
cd quick2wire-gpio-admin
```

If `src/gpio-admin.c` has

```
int size = snprintf(path, PATH_MAX, "/sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio%u/%s", pin, filename);
```

change it to

```
int size = snprintf(path, PATH_MAX, GPIO_CLASS_PATH "gpio%u/%s", pin, filename);
```

Then, run
    make

Then, run

```
make install
```

as root.

Comment: I am new to nodejs. Can you please outline the steps to get the newest version.

Comment: It still doesnt work. I get the same error. I updated pi-gpio and also within the Samples folder, I executed the git clone command. I used Sudo for all the commands

Comment: @MuralidaranShanmugham It looks like that the function `allow_access_by_user` in `src/gpio-admin.c` in gpio-admin has not yet started to use the new path for gpio. And it is not recommended that you run `make` as root. You need root permission to run `make install` , but you don't need root permission to build it. It can be potentially dangerous to build software as root. See this: https://superuser.com/questions/205044/proper-way-to-build-from-sources

Comment: I made the changes as suggested. I get a zero value.    pi@raspberrypi:~/Samples/mygpio-admin $ sudo make
pi@raspberrypi:~/Samples/mygpio-admin $ sudo make install
pi@raspberrypi:~/Samples $ node GPIO.js'
0

Comment: But when I use my python program, I can get the reading from the sensor